# Can the RESTful service set its request and response type from "Accept" property of the client

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest, wcf-rest

Can a RESTFul service's request and response be serverd dynamically based on the "Accept" property of the client

i.e. If the client can "Accept" application/xml then my service should automatically understand that the request and response should be of type xml and process the request accordingly.

Hence, I would not create another service for client who want request/response in json and the same service should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact WCF can be configured to do this for you: [WCF Web HTTP Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx)

> When enabled, automatic formatting chooses the best format in which to
>   return the response. It determines the best format by checking the
>   following, in order:
>
> 1. The media types in the request message’s Accept header.
> 2. The content-type of the request message.
> 3. The default format setting in the operation.
> 4. The default format setting in the WebHttpBehavior.

Also, see the documentation for [`<webHttpEndpoint>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816921.aspx), specifically the `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
It probably should be the preferred way to negotiate content type.

That said, a content type override you can specify in an URL can be convenient to debug GETs from a browser. (i.e. myResource.json will be equivalent to myResource with Accept json)

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy with [WCF Web Api Content negotiation](http://blog.malevy.net/2011/06/messin-with-wcf-web-api-part-ii-content.html). Just set the Accept Header and it's done.